# Нужно разбить дубликаты значений из MySQL по массивам

Tags: php, mysql

Получаю все дубликаты

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM ali WHERE city IN (
SELECT city
FROM ali
GROUP BY city
HAVING COUNT( city ) > 1
) ORDER BY id";
```

Сейчас

`Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [city] => Dnipro
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [city] => Dnipro
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [city] => Dnipro
)
Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [city] => Rivne
)
Array
(
    [id] => 5
    [city] => Rivne
)
Array
(
    [id] => 7
    [city] => Kyiv
)
Array
(
    [id] => 8
    [city] => Kyiv
)`

Нужно разбить по массивам

```
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [city] => Dnipro
        )
        Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [city] => Dnipro
        )
        Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [city] => Dnipro
        )
   [1] => Array
       (
            [id] => 4
            [city] => Rivne
       )...`
```

Comment: Ну так разбейте. В чем проблема?

Comment: @Максим Степанов Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$resultArray = [];

array_walk($array, function($item, $key) use (&$resultArray) {
    $resultArray[$item['city']][] = $item;
});

print_r($resultArray);
```